# Update forms base table

Tags: oracle, forms, triggers

I created a 5 column tabular form, 3 of them with LOVs on them. When the form is  updated/inserted/deleted, how to update those columns that not showing on the form, such as LAST_UPDATE_DATE & LAST_UPDATED_BY?

I created a block trigger ON-UPDATE with an update statement to update those columns, but nothing can be saved and no error. And then I wrote a procedure called by ON-UPDATE trigger. Both did not work out. Did I miss something? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be resolved by adding 2 block level triggers PRE-INSERT and PRE-UPDATE with fnd_standard.set_who;on them.